# IOS scrolling text view in popover not showing all of text upon device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have an iPad popover containing a scrolling text view that is initiated via a custom toolbar button item   through a IB defined segue. Upon device rotation, the size of the popover is changed in code via the popoverContentSize property to handle the changes from portrait to landscape orientation and vice-versa. The scrolling view contains a number of equivalent pages of attributed text that is programmatically added to the scrolling text view.

All of the text appears just fine when in the portrait orientation, but when I change to the landscape orientation the last paragraph or so of the text does not appear in the rotated scrolling text view. What am I missing or not doing? How can I make all of the text appear in the landscape view as well? I appreciate any advice that anyone can give.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't change the `frame` of the textview when you changed size of the popover.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the frameSize and contentSize of the textView as dynamic based on the screen width and height (orientation) and refresh the values on rotation of device.